# Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, eclipselink, mysql-error-1054

By using EclipseLink JPA2.0 I have build an application which was working fine. Then I add some attribute in a table and regenerate that table entity.

But when I call create method by facade(session bean) on that particular entity that throws exception that first new column does not exist. When I removed that column from entity then error went for second new column.

But columns exist in table with same name. In-fact I have re-generated all entities via netbeans

Code is working fine on one machine but throwing exception continuously on other machine. even with same code same environment.

[#|2013-06-06T18:07:36.220+0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta|_ThreadID=47;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5054: Unexpected error occurred in after completion
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ixsCenterFrequency' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO greenacs_rev.cpe (campingTime, cpeTimestamp, custId, ddvVersion, idFirstUseDate, idHardwareVersion, idModemFirmwareVersion, idSerialNumber, idSoftwareVersion, idUpTime, ifConfig, illMacAddress, illlInterfaceIPAddress, illlInterfaceSubnetMask, ilwAutoChannelEnable, ilwBSSID, ilwChannel, ilwStandard, ilwTotalByteReceived, ilwTotalByteSent, ilwTransmitPower, imConnectionRequestPassword, imConnectionRequestURL, imConnectionRequestUsername, imParameterKey, imPassword, imPeriodicInformInterval, imPeriodicTime, imURL, imUsername, ioAccountName, iosRealm, iosType, iowccProviderIdentifier, iowhProviderIdentifier, isvlStatus, isvlcCallForwardOnNoAnswerNumber, isvlsAuthPassword, isvlsAuthUserName, isvlsX_UserAccount, isvsOutboundProxy, isvsOutboundProxyPort, isvvDigitMap, isvxRxGain, isvxTxGain, iuISPHomePage, iwwWANAccessType, iwwrFirmwareVersion, iwwrSotwareVersion, iwwwDNSServers, iwwwDefaultGateway, iwwwExternalIPaddress, iwwwMacAddress, iwwwMaxMTUSize, iwwwSubnetMask, iwwwnoOfRetires, ixDownlinkMeanCINR, ixDownlinkMeanRSSI, ixPHYDLmcs, ixPHYULmcs, ixServingBSID, ixfFullbandScanClass, ixlHoldOnLastGoodBSEnable, ixlLastGoodBSsScanEnable, ixlNeighborBSsScanEnable, ixsCenterFrequency, ixsDisconnectReason, ixsDownlinkDataRate, ixsNumberBytesReceived, ixsNumberBytesTransmitted, ixsNumberPktsReceived, ixsNumberPktsReceivedWithError, ixsNumberPktsTransmitted, ixsSecurity, ixsTxMeanPower, ixsUplinkDataRate, ixwcCAPLScanEnable, ixwcNAPFilterEnable, ixwcRECONNECT_ACTIVE, ixwcSupplicantAnonymousIDEnable, lastSyncTime, hmId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [82 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(kics.green.acs.ejb.entity.CPE[ cpeId=1 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.jts.jta.SynchronizationImpl.before_completion(SynchronizationImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:158)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TopCoordinator.java:2547)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorTerm.commit(CoordinatorTerm.java:279)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TerminatorImpl.commit(TerminatorImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentImpl.commit(CurrentImpl.java:623)
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:175)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:858)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5114)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDeliveryInternal(MessageBeanContainer.java:1207)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1180)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:143)
    at $Proxy308.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ixsCenterFrequency' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:685)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1314)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
    ... 54 more
|#]

Comment: Are you sure both machines are accessing the same database?  Sounds like the one having the problems is accessing a different, unchanged database schema.  Check the login credentials used.

Comment: both are not using same database but both have same schema, each database running on local machine where code is running.

Comment: Error is like that persistence manager unable to find new attribute in table or mysql shows those attribute exist but not add those column completely.

Comment: What do you mean " mysql shows those attribute exist but not add those column completely".  Is the column in the table or not?  How are you adding the column to the schema accessed by the failing app?